# proving a statement with multiple quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

F is just a field, and a,b,c are members. There are 3 quantifiers, which is a bit confusing for me, so I'm not sure where to start exactly.
I get that C should be "universal", but then I get stuck.
$$
\forall a\in \mathbb F \quad \exists b\in \mathbb F \quad \forall c \in \mathbb F \quad c+b=1_\mathbb F\quad \Longrightarrow \quad a(ac+1)=0_\mathbb F
$$

Comment: Hint:  Distinguish two cases, $a=0, a\neq 0$.  If $a=0$ then any $b$ you choose will work.  If $a\neq 0$, you will have to solve for the only $b$ which will work.

Comment: Just stating (1-b) as c, in the second expression?

Comment: @Anacardium  Yes, it is.  Remember, you only need to find a single $b$ that works.  Side note:  I don't understand your example.  If $a=1$ then I just choose $b=2$.  In that case we must have $c=-1$ and we get $a\times (ac+1)=1\times (-1+1)=0$ as desired.

Comment: @Anacardium  I think you are assuming that the result is meant to hold $\forall b$.  That would certainly be false, but the claim only says that there exists a good $b$.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I thought it was given $\forall b.$

Comment: Take $b=1_{\Bbb F}+a^{-1}$.